# Kendo Ui Mobile ActionSheet Element Keeps Highlighted in Android Browser and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, uiactionsheet, android-browser, kendo-mobile

I have a kendo-ui core mobile application.

In the actionsheet, the selected item "li" is sometimes kept selected (highlighted).. it doesn't prevent the usage of the application. But gives a feeling like the option is sticked from the previous operation.

has any experienced a similar problem before?

---

EDIT !

I realized that this bug only appears (and everytime happens) on the default browser of my android device and in the application that I build with Phonegap.. It works fine on Firefox mobile on the same device.

So I think somehow the actionsheet is not working on some android browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue opened in Github 3 months ago. I used the onCommand function and the problem was solved.

Please note that the data-command event handler doesn't exists on Telerik's documentation. But it exists on the current kendo-core releases.

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/308